# Array iteration by using two for loops and print the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods, console.log

**update 2:**

right now we will get 16 small arrays when we slice it, we need to add the all 16 small arrays and find out which one is greater.
so i added two for loops to iterate the small array sets and debugged the code, but instead of printing 16 times, its printing 27 times.
Can you tell me whats the problem. Providing my updated code snippet below

First set of Array:

> ```
> +------------+           --- outerIndex
> | 0   0    0  |  0   0    0    |  
> |             |                |
> | 5   5    5  |  0   0    0    |
> |             |               \|/ outerSize
> |10  10   10  |  0   0    0   ---
>  +------------+
>  0    0    0    0    0    0
>
>  5    5    5    0    0    0
>
> 10   10   10    0    0    0
> ```

**Second set of Array:**

> ```
>    +--------------+           --- outerIndex
>  0 |  0    0    0 |  0    0    |  
>    |              |            |
>  5 |  5    5    0 |  0    0    |
>    |              |           \|/ outerSize
> 10 | 10   10    0 |  0    0   ---
>    +--------------+
>  0    0    0    0    0    0
>
>  5    5    5    0    0    0
>
> 10   10   10    0    0    0
> ```

```
function getSum(array) {
    return array.reduce((s, v) => s + (Array.isArray(v) ? getSum(v) : v), 0);
}

function getSub2D(array, outerIndex, outerSize, innerIndex, innerSize) {


    return array
        .slice(outerIndex, outerIndex + outerSize)
        .map(a => a.slice(innerIndex, innerIndex + innerSize));
}


function hourglassSum(arr) {

    let array = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0]];

    let    twoDimensionalAdded = 0;

    for (let outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < array.length; outerLoop++) {
       // console.log("array.length--->", array.length);
        for (let innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < array[outerLoop].length; innerLoop++) {
            //console.log("array[outerLoop].length--->", array[outerLoop].length);
            console.log("outerLoop--->", outerLoop);
            console.log("innerLoop--->", innerLoop);

            let sub = getSub2D(array, outerLoop, 3, innerLoop, 3);
            let total = getSum(sub);
            sub.forEach(a => console.log("getSub2D--->", ...a));
            console.log("adding subset of whole array--->", total);
            console.log("array[outerLoop][innerLoop]--->", array[outerLoop][innerLoop]);
           // twoDimensionalAdded += array[outerLoop][innerLoop]; // add item to sum
        }
    }
   // console.log("twoDimensionalAdded--->", twoDimensionalAdded);

    // let sub = getSub2D(array, outerLoop, 3, innerLoop, 3);
    // let sub = getSub2D(array, 0, 3, 0, 3);
   // let total = getSum(sub);

    // sub.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
    // console.log(total);



}
```

**update1**:

Hi,

Now I am able to add the elements in an array and print the values, but to solve my problem i need to add the values of `dimensionalTwo[0][1], dimensionalTwo[0][2], dimensionalTwo[0][3], dimensionalTwo[1][1], dimensionalTwo[1][2], dimensionalTwo[1][3], dimensionalTwo[2][1], dimensionalTwo[2][2], dimensionalTwo[2][3]` separately and print the results, providing my updated code snippet below

```
function adding particularSet(arr) {

    let dimensionalTwo = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0]];
    let    twoDimensionalAdded = 0;

    for (let outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < dimensionalTwo.length; outerLoop++) {
        for (let innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < dimensionalTwo[outerLoop].length; innerLoop++) {

            console.log("dimensionalTwo[outerLoop][innerLoop]--->", dimensionalTwo[outerLoop][innerLoop]);
            twoDimensionalAdded += dimensionalTwo[outerLoop][innerLoop]; // add item to sum
        }
    }
    console.log("twoDimensionalAdded--->", twoDimensionalAdded);
```

}

- I'm new to js.
- I am trying to iterate a two dimensional array and add the values then print it.
- But the the problem is I am not able to print the values.
- It would be great if you let me know.
- So that I can iterate my array and print results for my future tasks.
- Providing my code snippet below

```or-tag-here
var DimensionalTwo = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [5, 5, 5],
    [10, 10, 10]
];

for (let outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < DimensionalTwo.length; outerLoop++) {
  for (let innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < DimensionalTwo[outerLoop].length; innerLoop++) {
    console.log("DimensionalTwo[outerLoop][innerLoop]--->", DimensionalTwo[outerLoop][innerLoop]);
    let TwoDimensonalTemporayStorage = DimensionalTwo[outerLoop][innerLoop];
    let twoDimensionalAdded = TwoDimensonalTemporayStorage + DimensionalTwo[outerLoop][innerLoop];
    console.log("twoDimensionalAdded--->", twoDimensionalAdded);

  }
  //console.log("inner for loop twoDimensionalAdded--->", twoDimensionalAdded);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array with the offsets for the array for counting.

```
[
    [-1, -1], [-1,  0], [-1,  1],
              [ 0,  0],
    [ 1, -1], [ 1,  0], [ 1,  1]
]
```

```js
var array = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0], [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0]],
    hourglass = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 0], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]],
    totals = array.map(a => a.map(_ => 0)), // get an array with all zero values
    i, j, k;

for (i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < array[i].length - 1; j++) {
       totals[i][j] = 0;
       for (k = 0; k < hourglass.length; k++) {
           totals[i][j] += array[i + hourglass[k][0]][j + hourglass[k][1]];
       }
    }
}

totals.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: hey it worked, but if I increase the number of elements in an array its not adding in the expected way for particular set, updated my question, can you help me

Comment: right now I dont see any error, not sure how to add the first set of values alone like this one `dimensionalTwo[0][1], dimensionalTwo[0][2], dimensionalTwo[0][3], dimensionalTwo[1][1], dimensionalTwo[1][2], dimensionalTwo[1][3], dimensionalTwo[2][1], dimensionalTwo[2][2], dimensionalTwo[2][3]`

Comment: hey I looked at your code I am not able to follow. Can you give comments, its hard to understand or I wont learn anything :(. What does outerIndex, outerSize, innerIndex, innerSize mean and how your calculating it...it will help me to proceed further

Comment: hey I printed the values. I am getting results like this `outerIndex ----> 0
outerSize ----> 3
innerIndex ----> 1
innerSize ----> 3` . Not sure how this values are assigned for  outerIndex, outerSize, innerIndex, innerSize

Comment: hey thanks for updating the answer, but still can you tell me why you have assigned outerIndex value as 0 and innerIndex value as  1. It will me to understand the code :(

Comment: and in this line `array.reduce((s, v)`, you have used two parameter s,v. Can you let me know why your using s aparameter since using v paramter your checking whether its an array or not right?

Comment: `s` is the accumulator for the sum and `v` is a value of the array, which could be an array. the outer and inner indices for getting a subset of an array are derived from the given `dimensionalTwo[0][1]` and so on. obviously, you want to get a subset of the matrix.

Comment: thanks for your response, I am learning lot of stuffs from you, actually right now we will get 16 small arrays when we slice it, we need to add the all 16 small arrays and find out which one is greater.
so i added two for loops and iterated the small array sets and debugged the code, **but instead of printing 16 times, its printing 27 times.**
Can you tell me whats the problem. Providing my updated code snippet in the question

Comment: i have no idea, what you want.

Comment: I am teying to solve a hackerrank problem, I wanted to solve myself, thats the reason I debugged so many times and updated the question...can you please help me **There are  hourglasses in , and an hourglass sum is the sum of an hourglass' values. Calculate the hourglass sum for every hourglass in , then print the maximum hourglass sum.

For example, given the 2D array:** https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays

Comment: hey can you tell me why you declared hourglass like this `hourglass = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 0], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]],` and  in console can you give any comments it will help me to analyze the code, since I am beginner very difficult for me `console.log("added", ...a)`

Comment: `hourglass` contains the offsets of the indices for using with an index of the loops of `i` and `j` of the array. the console.log is in this case only to have an output item by item and line by line.

Comment: hey can you tell me how your giving -1,-1, it would be great if you explain by a diagram...so that it will help us in understanding

Comment: so [-1,-1] means which set of array elements and why your using the term offset here?

Comment: assuming, you like to get the sum of element `[1][1]` (value: 5), then you have `i = 1` and `j = 1` and you need to sum the elements, you got with the `hourglass` items, where the first pair resolves to `[1 + (-1)][1 + (-1)]`, which is `[0][0] (0)`. the second goes to `[1 + (-1)][1 + 0]`, which is `[0][1]` (0) and so on.

Comment: sorry I was not well, i tried to understand your comments...its so confusing...its possible to explain using diagram :(

Comment: actually i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
          Let's simply represent this entire problem space differently. 
          Let's reconceive homogeneous, higher-order, JS arrays as two-
          dimensional, algebraic arrays instead of JS arrays, since JS 
          is not natively well-suited for this. 

          First, a few utility functions for handling arrays...
        */

        // calculate and return the sums of all the desired subarrays - 
        // relies on functions that treat JS arrays *differently*;
        // current implementations assumes that square subarrays of shape 
        // {size x size} are desired
        function calcSubSums(arr, size) {
            var sums = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - size + 1; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length - size + 1; j++) {
                     sums.push(reduce(ravel(getSubArray(arr,[i,j],size))));
                }
            }
            return sums;
        };

        // for an array, arr, return subarray that starts at the top-left-
        // corner indexes tlc (top-row-index, left-column-index) for an 
        // extent of size on each dimension
        function getSubArray(arr, tlc, size) {
            var a = new Array();
            for (var i = tlc[0]; i < size + tlc[0]; i++) {
                var b = new Array();
                for (var j = tlc[1]; j < size + tlc[1]; j++) {
                    b.push(arr[i][j]);
                }
                a.push(b);
            }
            return a;
        };

        // convert a higher dimensional array into one-dimensional array 
        // that contains all of its elements, unpacking from top-to-bottom, 
        // left-to-right
        function ravel(arr, flat) {
            // If flat - accumulator array - not yet defined, create it.
            if ('undefined' == typeof flat) flat = new Array();
            // If arg is an array, iterate over the elements in index order.
            if (isArray(arr)) {
                // Call self recursively to get elements or process next, 
                // outermost level of nesting.
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ravel(arr[i], flat); }
            }
            // Otherwise, just add simple element to accumulator.
            else flat.push( arr );
            // Return accumulated values.
            return flat;
        };

        // return a Boolean indicator of whether the argument is a JS array
        function isArray(a) {
            if ('undefined' == typeof a) {return false};
            return -1 != a.constructor.toString().indexOf('Array');
        };

        // place the operator {op} between the elements of a and evaluate the 
        // entire, resulting expression
        function reduce(a, op) {
            // Set default op (add/concatenate), if not given.
            if ('undefined' == typeof op) op = '+';
            // Initialize command to evaluate.
            var cmd = '';
            // Compose command string - concatenate each element with op.
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {cmd += a[i] + op;}
            // Remove, extraneous, trailing instance of op and return evaluation.
            return eval(cmd.substring(0, cmd.length - op.length));
        };

        // now let's test it...
        window.onload = function() {
        // declare the test array
            var array = [
                [ 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0], 
                [ 5,  5,  5, 0, 0, 0], 
                [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0], 
                [ 0,  0,  0, 0, 0, 0], 
                [ 5,  5,  5, 0, 0, 0], 
                [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0]
            ];
        // calculate all of the sums of 3x3 subset arrays of our test array 
        // and write the totals to the console
            console.log(calcSubSums(array, 3));
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```